# Data node capacity is too low on the server

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using hortonworks distribution of hadoop and have installed it with ambari.

I have it installed on the server and there aren't any space constraints as such.

Yet my datanode is given only 991 MB of space which is surprisingly low.

What could be the possible reasons ?How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try df -g from Linux terminal to confirm you have enough space.

Login to Amabari UI --> HDFS tab --> config, search for the property dfs.datanode.du.reserved
This property defines the space reserved that will not be used for Hadoop.